# How to upload any file (.zip, spreedsheet) using fetch in React Native

Tags: react-native, file-upload

I want to upload any file from mobile directory to server in React Native. Although i am succeeded to upload images, Audio and Video files but unable to rest of them like zip file or excel file any other. please help me in this regard